# RFID transponder cards no unique atr

Tags: python, smartcard, rfid, smartcard-reader, pcsc

I bought some RFID transponder cards for building an identification system with the unique identifier on the cards.
I setup a `testenv` under Ubuntu 12.04 and I work with the `pcscd` deamon and the scm scl011 card reader.

The problem is that all my cards have the same ATR and I cannot extract a unique id.

I used `pcsc_scan` for getting ATR's, then I tried a pyscard sample script to get most of the cards' ATR's. The result for the pyscard action was that a lot ATR's are not supported or they don't differ from the other card.

Does somebody have an idea what the problem is here?

- [Link Transponder](http://www.ebay.de/itm/200359479839?ssPageName=STRK%3aMEWNX%3aIT&_trksid=p3984.m1497.l2649#ht_1437wt_1397)
- [Pyscard](http://pyscard.sourceforge.net/Examples/scard-api/sample_getAttrib.py)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The cards of the same type should be expected to have the same [ATR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Answer_to_reset).  You'll need to understand the [attributes](http://www.idautomation.com/barcode-faq/rfid/#TagDataConstructExamples) that go on your cards, including whether the vendor has pre-programmed them with tags, and if so, whether those tags include UIDs (that identify individual items) or EPCs (that identify just a class of item, as with barcodes in the grocery store).  Almost certainly the vendor of your cards has not pre-programmed them, and you are expected to format them for your purpose prior to using them.  If you were buying a bunch of physical ID cards for your employees, you wouldn't expect them to already have your employees' pictures and ID numbers on them - you need to put that information on the cards before issuing them to the employee.

Comment: Thanks so much, so i will ask the seller for putting an unique tag on the card, cuz buying an rfid write is kinda valuable. I hope so i can start over afer that.